# Is there any way to change created and modified date on SPList programmatically?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

I'm migrating some discussions on my SharePoint site - SPsite - from excel file. 
In my tests, SharePoint obviously sets the created and modified date to the upload time. I know how to change these values on SPListItem, but my problem is setting these values on SPList.
Is there any way to change these attributes to the value coming from the excel file?

Regards,
Veronica

Comment: Please elaborate. It would help if you can show the code that you are working on.

Comment: Why? It doesn't seem reasonable to try to fiddle with `SPList.Created`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on SPList.Folders in order to do that. Here are the magic functions:

```
private static void UpdateDatesOfAllItemsInTheList(SPList list, DateTime date)
{
    // For each message (NOT thread) in the list.
    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        ChangeDate(item, date);
    }

    // For each thread.
    foreach (SPListItem folder in list.Folders)
    {
        ChangeDate(folder, date);
    }
}

private static void ChangeDate(SPListItem item, DateTime date)
{
    // Open fields for edits.
    item.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified].ReadOnlyField = false;
    item.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created].ReadOnlyField = false;
    item.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.DiscussionLastUpdated].ReadOnlyField = false;

    // Edit fields.
    item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created] = date;
    item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified] = date;
    item[SPBuiltInFieldId.DiscussionLastUpdated] = date;

    // Save changes.
    item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```